# Spring Boot Spring Security Configuration Issue After Upgrade to 3.1.3

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm upgrading a Spring Boot application from version 2.7.14 to 3.1.3, and I'm having issues with my Spring Security configuration. The relevant security configuration is stored in a separate JAR file, and I've refactored my security config class to use SecurityFilterChain. However, the new configuration doesn't seem to take effect.

Here's a simplified structure of my application:

Basic module (Contains SecurityConfig in com.mypackage.config)
App module (Depends on the basic module)
In the app module, I have the following configuration:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mypackage</groupId>
    <artifactId>basic-auth</artifactId>
    <version>${basic.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

And in the main class of the app module there is this setting:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.mypackage"})
```

Here's my old and new security configuration classes:

Old Configuration (Working):

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "auth.oauth2.enabled", havingValue = "true")
@Order(26)
public class Oauth2SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      // ...
    }
}
```

New Configuration (Not working):

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "auth.oauth2.enabled", havingValue = "true")
@Order(26)
public class Oauth2SecurityConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain oauth2SecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // ...
    }
}
```

When I use the new Oauth2SecurityConfiguration, it doesn't seem to get applied. However, if I copy the exact same class into my application, it works as expected.

When the application starts, I can see through debugging that the Oauth2SecurityConfiguration  class is being instantiated when its in the basic module.

When I enabled debug, the filterChains seem like this:

Config class in basic, not working:

```
Security filter chain: [
  DisableEncodeUrlFilter
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextHolderFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  LogoutFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  AuthorizationFilter
]
```

Config class moved to application, working

```
Security filter chain: [
  DisableEncodeUrlFilter
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextHolderFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  LogoutFilter
  OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter
  OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter
  DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter
  DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  AuthorizationFilter
]
```

Any insights into why the new configuration isn't recognized would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you add `@EnableWebSecuriry` so the auto-configuration (partially) backsoff?

Comment: Thank for the tip, I tried now, added '@EnableWebSecurity' to the main class in app: not worked; after it I added it to the configuration class in basic: the result is the same, not working. :(
But before it the '@EnableWebSecurity' annotation not existed in the code.

Comment: Is the configuration being scanned and detected?

Comment: When I turn on logging.level.org.springframework.core.io.support=DEBUG, logging.level.org.springframework.context.annotation=DEBUG; in the log there is a relevant line: 'o.s.c.a.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner   : Identified candidate component class: file [C:\workspace\...\config\Oauth2SecurityConfiguration.class]'
And when the application starts, breakpoint stops in the basic module oauth2SecurityFilterChain method.
Is there anything that I can check?

Comment: That should do the trick then. Have you tried naming the method `securityFilterChain` instead of `oauth2SecurityFilterChain`. Or adding a `name="securityFilterChain"` to the `@Bean`?

Comment: Now I tried ` @Bean(name = "securityFilterChain")
    public SecurityFilterChain oauth2SecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {` in basic module, still not working. (I'm getting http 403)
The interesting thing is that i moved the configuration into the App module worked without any other configuration

Comment: What do you mean with *moved the configuration into the App module*? Copy the class? The bean method?

Comment: Yes, I copied the whole Configuration class from basic module to the app module, and comment it out from the basic module so basicly moved the entire class

Comment: Weird. What happens if you remove the `@ComponentScan` and use an `@Import(YourConfiguration.class)` instead?

Comment: This was seems working, oauth login appears, thanks for the tip!
But I have more class to load, so now I have to find a way to load classes that previously loaded by the ComponentScan annotation.
My current config like this:

//@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.mypackage"})
@Import({Oauth2SecurityConfiguration.class, AuthUtil.class, AuthProperties.class})

These 2 classes were necessary to get the application started, but i need a lot more in runtime.

Comment: Still is weird that the `@Import` works. Instead of an `@ComponentScan` what happens if you use `scanBasePackages` on the `@SpringBootApplication`. Include both the package in which the `@SpringBootApplication` is in and the additional one you want to scan.

Comment: I tried different ways with scanBasePackaes, none of them worked:
scanBasePackages = {"com.mypackage", "com.mypackage.config"})
scanBasePackages = {"com.mypackage", "com.mypackage.config.Oauth2SecurityConfiguration"})
scanBasePackages = {"com.mypackage"})

ComponentScan and Import was removed

Comment: If the package is already covered by the main package you don't need an `@ComponentScan`. But there must be something special in your dedicated project that stops it from being registered correctly/fully. With all you tried and added I suspect there is too little information here and with the snippets we have we will not be able to answer it.

Comment: You could [edit] your question to update it instead of adding comments. Code is unreadable in comments, and they are shown by number of votes, not chronologically. Would be easier to have everything in one place rather than expecting people to put all the puzzle pieces everything together.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution; there were multiple securityFilterChains defined in my application, and their settings conflicted. Using SecurityMatcher resolved the issue.